# How would I display "New account is created" message after new user have registered

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

My concern is I want after a user is registered a message should display  indicating that a user is registered, I have already added a script but when I click a sign up button a message pop up even I have not registered a user. I am not sure where and how should I place my scripts but I guess if function is required. Help!!

views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f"New account created:{username}")
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("loststuffapp:IndexView")

    else:
        for msg in user_form.error_messages:
            messages.error(request, f"{msg}:{form.error_messages[msg]}")
        return render(request = request,
                      template_name = "loststuffapp/register.html",
                      context={"user_form":user_form})

user_form = UserCreationForm
return render(request = request,
              template_name = "loststuffapp/register.html",
              context={"user_form":user_form})
```

register.html

```
{% extends "loststuffapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
   <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{user_form.as_p}}

       <p><button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button></p>

       <script>M.toast({html: "New account is created", classes: 'blue 
rounded', displayLength:2000});</script>
   </form>

        <p>If you already have an account, <a href="/Register">login</a> 
instead</p>
       {% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
       <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="/login">Sign in</a></li>
      <li><a href="/register">Sign up</a></li>
      <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
```

home.html

```
{% extends "loststuffapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="/PostNew">Add documents</a>
 {% for Doc in documents %}
 <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">

    <p>{{Doc.docs_name}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.item_type}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.police_station}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.phone_no}}</p>
    <p>{{Doc.Description}}</p>
    <p><img src = "/media/{{Doc.image.url}}" width = "240"/></p>
    <p>{{Doc.date}}</p>

</div>
```

```
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How do you trigger `M.toast({html: ...})`?

Comment: add `loststuffapp:IndexView` template code

Comment: I have just copied from somewhere not sure

Comment: @Anjaneyulu Batta  I have added already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `messages` framework in django. Add below code inside template block `content`

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Refernce: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages